# 欠損値を含む2変数の内容を1変数にまとめる方法

Tags: python, pandas

python のデータフレームに、
部屋の面積の入っている二つの変数xとyがあります。

xから、面積のデータを取り出し、
yにも入っている面積のデータを、取り出して、
面積のみを含む変数spaceを作りたいと考えています。

このことを意図してfor roop とif を用いて、
spaceを作ろうとしていますが、エラーが生じて進みません。

エラーをなくす方法、あるいは別の方法がございましたら、ご教示頂けるとありがたいです。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['15平米', '5分', '16平米'],
     'y':[np.nan, '16平米', np.nan]},
    index=[1,2,3])

#単位を削除
df["space"] = df.x.str.extract(r'(\d*)平米')
df["y"] = df.y.str.extract(r'(\d*)平米')

# 欠損値でないyをspaceに代入する。
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df["y"][i]!=np.nan:
        df['space'][i] =df['y'][i]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> エラーをなくす方法、あるいは別の方法がございましたら、ご教示頂けるとありがたいです。

以下を確認すると、行のラベルは1〜3が設定されています。

```
print(df['y'])
1    NaN
2     16
3    NaN
Name: y, dtype: object
```

そのため、行のラベルでアクセスしないと情報がとれないようです。

```
print(df['y'][1], df['y'][2], df['y'][3])
nan 16 nan
```

以下ではエラーになります。

```
print(df['y'][0])
```

インデックスでアクセスする場合は、 dfのiatを使うようです。

```
print(df['y'].iat[0], df['y'].iat[1], df['y'].iat[2])
nan 16 nan
```

また、NaNのチェックは pd.isnull を使うようです。

そのため、以下のようにすれば解決できそうです。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['15平米', '5分', '16平米'],
     'y':[np.nan, '16平米', np.nan]},
    index=[1,2,3])

#単位を削除
df["space"] = df.x.str.extract(r'(\d*)平米')
df["y"] = df.y.str.extract(r'(\d*)平米')

# 欠損値でないyをspaceに代入する。
for i in range(len(df)):
    if not pd.isnull(df["y"].iat[i]):
        df['space'].iat[i] =df['y'].iat[i]
```

結果は、以下になります。

```
print(df)
      x    y space
1  15平米  NaN    15
2    5分   16    16
3  16平米  NaN    16
```

Comment: お陰様で、エラーを消すことができました。有用なご回答をいただき、感謝いたします。

Answer (score 4):

pamdasらしく書くと、位置を指定する`loc`と欠損値でないことを評価する`notnull`を使うと次のようになります。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['15平米', '5分', '16平米'],
     'y':[np.nan, '16平米', np.nan]},
    index=[1,2,3])

#単位を削除
df['space'] = df.x.str.extract(r'(\d*)平米')
df['y'] = df.y.str.extract(r'(\d*)平米')

df.loc[df["y"].notnull(),'space'] = df['y']
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。私なりに解釈すると, 右辺のdf['y']を左辺に代入し、左辺は、df['y']のnan以外のセルに'space'の内容を代入せよ、というように解釈しました。